# Error: equations for ‘testListTuple’ have different numbers of arguments

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to do a function that gets an `Expression` and a `list of tuples (a pair of strings)`, according to the following code:

```
module Test where

import Data.List

type Symbol = String

data Expression = Var Symbol    -- variable
    | Lambda Symbol Expression  -- abstraction
    | App Expression Expression -- application
    deriving (Eq, Read)

expTest = Lambda "x" $ Lambda "y" $ (Var "x" `App` Var "y")

testListTuple :: Expression -> [(Symbol,Symbol)] -> [Symbol]
testListTuple (exp) ((a,b):xs) = functionTest (exp) (a) (b) : testListTuple (exp) (xs)
testListTuple _          = []


functionTest :: Expression -> Symbol -> Symbol -> Symbol
functionTest _ a b = a ++ b

runTest = testListTuple expTest [("a", "b"), ("c", "d")]
```

However, the following error is displayed:

[image]

After resolving this error, I will still finish implementing the `functionTest`.

Comment: Uh. Give them the same number of arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in exactly what compiler says. Equations for `testListTuple` have different numbers of arguments.

The first equation has two : `testListTuple (exp) ((a,b):xs) = ...`.

The second one has one: `testListTuple _ = []`

The correct definition is:

```
testListTuple :: Expression -> [(Symbol,Symbol)] -> [Symbol]
testListTuple exp ((a,b):xs) = functionTest exp a b : testListTuple exp xs
testListTuple _ _ = []
```

Comment: I'm amazed how I forgot that little detail. A very stupid mistake. Excuse me.